# Como fazer um relacionamento com dois itens de uma mesma tabela no Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, orm, sequelize-js

Tenho uma tabela que guarda dois ID's de usuários. O `UserId` e o `ResponsibleId`,  ambos pegam da tabela `User`.

**Model**:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Table = sequelize.define(
        'Table',
        {
            UserId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                references: {
                    model: 'User',
                    key: 'id'
                },
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
                onDelete: 'CASCADE'
            },
            ResponsibleId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                references: {
                    model: 'User',
                    key: 'id'
                },
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
                onDelete: 'CASCADE'
            }
        }
    );

    Table.associate = models => {
        Table.hasOne(models.User, {
            foreignKey: 'id',
            sourceKey: 'UserId',
            as: 'user'
        });
        Table.hasOne(models.User, {
            foreignKey: 'id',
            sourceKey: 'ResponsibleId',
            as: 'responsible'
        });
    };

    return Table;
};
```

E a tabela User:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define(
        'User',
        {
            fullName: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            }
        },
    );

    User.associate = models => {
        User.belongsTo(models.Table, {
            foreignKey: 'id',
            sourceKey: 'UserId'
        });
        User.belongsTo(models.Table, {
            foreignKey: 'id',
            sourceKey: 'ResponsibleId'
        });
    };

    return User;
};
```

Porém quando eu tento realizar o `include` na *query*, só retorna o último relacionamento apontado (`Responsible`).

```
{
    model: User,
    as: 'responsible'
},
{
    model: User,
    as: 'user'
}
```

Como que eu posso fazer para que a *query* inclua os dados dos dois ID's no resultado da pesquisa?

Eu tentei usando `hasMany` mas não sei conseguir a separação dos ID's (um apontando para user e outro responsible) na *query* e o resultado vem o mesmo só que dentro de um array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui....

Em Users faz as associações assim:

```
User.associate = models => {
    User.belongsToMany(models.Table, {
        through: 'UserTable',
        foreignKey: 'UserId'
    });
    User.belongsToMany(models.Table, {
        through: 'ResponsibleTable',
        foreignKey: 'ResponsibleId'
    });
};
```

E na tabela se faz:

```
Table.associate = models => {
    Table.hasMany(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'id',
        sourceKey: 'ResponsibleId'
    });
    Table.hasMany(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'id',
        sourceKey: 'UserId'
    });
};
```